# Recompose a VMware vSphere machine without personal application data loss?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

Our organization has converted a large percentage of our employees to VDI. Our logic is that we create a master image for each linked-clone pool, dedicate each linked-clone pool to specific purposes (specific software for specific departments, etc.), and give each user/machine a persistent disk to keep their settings. All of their documents ("My Documents" folder) are stored on a network share, and with our current configuration, we have zero issues with this. The purpose of the pool is to allow for updates to the master (Java, Flash, anything else) periodically, and then recompose the pool over the weekend or during a non-business hour.

However, we have many issues after a recompose. Office requires going through the activation prompt and does not save any user-side settings (toolbar changes, add-on settings, Outlook signatures, etc). Nearly every other program suffers from this problem. Additionally, programs that we have been unable to thinapp are, of course, gone.

**Is it unreasonable to want an environment that does not change for the user after a recompose?** I've tried every keyword under the sun in a Google search, but I never find much more than documentation - not answers. We're probably going to try Persona Manager soon, but from my understanding, this will not solve our issues much more than the persistent disks do currently. Our "sales pitch" for virtualization has been that you have your same desktop everywhere, but that quickly becomes useless when the desktop changes every week or so.